# Agile Web Development

Tags: agile

I'm looking for some resources and information around agile web development. I have done a search and found a wiki page and lots of other sites around the subject. Most of these sites are orientated around Ruby on Rails. Does anyone know of any sites or resources that cover other platforms and languages like asp.net and php or are even generic.

Comment: The reason web searches are returning mainly Ruby on Rails results is that the most popular book about Ruby on Rails is titled "Agile Web Development with Rails" - http://pragprog.com/titles/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails-4th-edition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agile is an umbrella term for many methods (Scrum, eXtreme Programming, Crystal, DSDM, FDD, etc) and **none of them is language specific**. Now, the most frequently used nowadays are  [Scrum](http://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/topics/scrum) and [XP](http://www.extremeprogramming.org/) together (Scrum for the project organization and XP for the engineering practices).

Comment: Thanks everyone for their comments I took a look at the above mentioned methods. And took some notes for future reference books. 
Just to let you know we are going to try the scrum method.

Comment: @sidcom: You're welcome (and I hope you'll enjoy Scrum as much as I do).

Answer (score 3):

You can try the book "The Art of Agile Development".

Answer (score 3):

You might want to explore "Agile" in a broader sense then just web development. Checkout "Practices of an Agile Developer" (pragprog.com) as well as "The Pragmatic Programmer" (Addison Wesley) as those books can give you a good grounding in agile and personal development practices. Applying the lessons from these books to web development should become obvious.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on what you are trying to achieve by using "agile".  Agile by itself is just a statement of intent.  As the [manifesto](http://agilemanifesto.org/) points out it really is just four statements.

From these statements a lot of "best practice" has sprung up. For example [Extreme Programming](http://www.extremeprogramming.org/) could be seen as an implementation of the manifesto.

I would search the web, not for specific advice on `Agile Web Development`, but just `Agile Development`, as the practices are much the same.  Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

There's a great series of articles *just* on agile web development, describing how the agency that produced [GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/) did it: [Agile web design and the agency model](http://boagworld.com/business-strategy/agile-web-design/).

Comment: Probably most posters to this question have moved on.